# string array converts to enum

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys I just wanted to ask if it is possible

I am currently making a simple poker game and here's my array of string which has the value of

```
public static string[] cardSprite = new string[]
   {
        "1c", "1s", "1d", "1h", "2c", "2s", "2d", "2h", "3c", "3s", "3d", "3h",
        "4c", "4s", "4d", "4h", "5c", "5s", "5d", "5h", "6c", "6s", "6d", "6h",
        "7c", "7s", "7d", "7h", "8c", "8s", "8d", "8h", "9c", "9s", "9d", "9h",
        "10c", "10s", "10d", "10h", "11c", "11s", "11d", "11h", "12c", "12s", "12d", "12h",
        "13c", "13s", "13d", "13h",
   };
```

Now those value inside the array I used it to load the cards from my resources like this

```
Resources.Load<Sprite>
```

and store the original values on this variable

```
string[] cardplaceholderValue
```

Now its working perfectly but I am having trouble of getting the game rules of poker like
`onePair()` `twoPair()` etc.

So my solution for that is convert/put the `array` to `enum` but I am stuck so what on my mind is like this

```
public enum CardValue
    {
        ACE = 1,
        TWO = 2,
        THREE = 3,
        FOUR = 4,
        FIVE = 5,
        SIX = 6,
        SEVEN = 7,
        EIGHT = 8,
        NINE = 9,
        TEN = 10,
        JACK = 11,
        QUEEN = 12,
        KING = 13
    }
```

Here's the problem on my conditional statement

```
if(player1ValueCard[0] == player1ValueCard[1])
{
    ValueHolder.Player1OnePair = true;    
}
```

How will I know the value of my card that is converted into enum so that even if it is
`1 of heart or 1 of diamond or 1 of clover or 1 of spade` it will be considered as `ACE or 1`

### WHAT I"VE DONE SO FAR

**GAMERULE.CS**

```
public static void ConvertCards()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "1h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "1d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "1c"
                || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "1s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.ACE.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "2h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "2d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "2c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "2s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.TWO.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "3h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "3d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "3c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "3s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.THREE.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "4h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "4d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "4c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "4s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.FOUR.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "5h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "5d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "5c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "5s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.FIVE.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "6h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "6d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "6c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "6s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.SIX.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "7h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "7d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "7c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "7s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.SEVEN.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "8h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "8d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "8c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "8s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.EIGHT.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "9h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "9d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "9c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "9s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.NINE.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "10h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "10d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "10c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "10s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.TEN.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "11h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "11d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "11c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "11s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.JACK.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "12h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "12d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "12c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "12s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.QUEEN.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
            if (ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "13h" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "13d" || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "13c"
               || ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] == "13s")
            {
                ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = ValueHolder.CardValue.KING.ToString();
                Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
            }
        }
       
    }
```

I created this method and it can now convert the string array to the enum

I know it's not the efficient way but it's working .

Comment: Hint: A card have two distinct properties: It's value and it's face. Don't use a single property to store both of them.

Comment: You might use 2 Enum: one for the value and one for the "type".

Comment: @ZoharPeled kindly explain a bit more sir

Comment: Is there a way that I could just do this on an enum `ACE = "1s","1h","1c","1d"` something like that?

Comment: Basically, you want something like this:

`enum Rank {Ace = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3, ... King = 13}
enum Suit {Club, Diamond, Heart, Spade}

public interface ICard
{
    Rank Rank {get;}
    Suit Suit {get;}
}`

Comment: yes mr @ZoharPeled something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the first part of your string eg. the number with `str.Substring(0, 1);`. You don't need the Enum because you just set the value equal to the first part of the string (numbers from 1 to 13) anyway.

**Example:**

```cs
// Getting the first character of our string.
string temp = ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i].Substring(0, 1);

// Set the card equal to the Number (1, 2, 3, ...)
ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i] = temp;
Debug.Log(ValueHolder.shuffleDeck[i]);
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could just do this on an enum `ACE = "1s","1h","1c","1d"` something like that?

Comment: Can you be more specific sir sorry I don't understand a bit on how to implement this on my end .

Comment: Can I show you what I've done . Actually I kind of almost there but didn't implemented your code for now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224415/discussion-between-paula-and-mathewhd).

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I wouldn't be using string representations for your game logic. You'll eventually want to be able to compare card face values, as well as suits, and combinations of those. For that reason, I'd suggest 'breaking' your enum into parts using the `Flags` attribute. Here's an example of how I would start the code:

```
[Flags]
public enum Cards
{
    None = 0,
    Spades = 1 << 0,
    Hearts = 1 << 1,
    Diamonds = 1 << 2,
    Clubs = 1 << 3,

    Ace = 1 << 10,
    Two = 1 << 11,
    Three = 1 << 12,
    Four = 1 << 13,
    Five = 1 << 14,
    Six = 1 << 15,
    Seven = 1 << 16,
    Eight = 1 << 17,
    Nine = 1 << 18,
    Jack = 1 << 19,
    Queen = 1 << 20,
    King = 1 << 21,

    Suits = Spades | Hearts | Diamonds | Clubs,
    Values = Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Jack | Queen | King
}

public Cards GetSuit ( Cards c ) => c & Cards.Suits;
public Cards GetValue ( Cards c ) => c & Cards.Values;
/// <summary>
/// Will return the card value and suit name. E.g. AceSpades
/// </summary>
/// <param name="c">The Card enum representing the card value.</param>
/// <returns>The expanded string representation of the enum. E.g. "AceSpades"</returns>
public string GetCardAsString ( Cards c ) => $"{ GetValue ( c )}{ GetSuit ( c )}";
```

It's certainly not complete. And there's no valid value checking. For example, the previous code WOULD allow a Card to be assigned like this:

```
var newCard = Card.Ace | Card.Two | Card.Heats | Card.Diamonds;
```

So, you will need to decide at what point you're going to introduce bounds and value sanitisation.

You could also introduce another method containing a big switch statement (two in fact) to reduce Card.Ace to "1", and Card.Spades to "s", but I'm not quite sure that would benefit you here. The option is obviously there though.

Comment: Hello sir Milan , I only used those string representation for the cards that is on my Resources . So actually the only problem I am facing right now is checking the hands of each player . But thank you tho for the insight . I might use this if I am cleaning up my code . Thank you